# How can I change the label of a shipping method in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, label

I am developing a site using Magento v1.9.0.1. I need to change the label of some shipping methods, the ones called "Media Mail" and "Priority Mail 1-Day". Ideally, I would remove any dynamic naming and use the names that I want - "Standard" and "Priority Mail".

I have tried changing every .csv file that contains "Media Mail" in it, in every combination I can think of - which means I have changed the first entry, both entries, and the second entry. I have also tried these combinations while a cache flush in between each test.

I have also tried editing the getCode() method, located in apps/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Usps.php.

That is about the extent of what I know to look at. I'm new to web development and Magento, and this is a client request I can't overlook. Where can I change this?

Regards

Edit:

This is for anyone that has the same question, but hasn't found the answer. The way to change the labels is to find the shipping.phtml and available.phtml files and edit code within them. If you inspect their elements you can find the attributes and corresponding php code that adds the titles in. I changed them using some simple if-else chains to eliminate the titles I didn't want and echo the ones is did:

```
<input name="estimate_method" type="radio" 
    value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getCode()) ?>" 
    id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"
    <?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) 
    echo 'checked="checked"' ?> class="radio" />
<label for="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>">
<?php 

/* my edits */
if( $_rate->getCode() === "usps_6" ) 
{ echo "Your Title Here "; } 
else if( $_rate->getCode() === "usps_1")
{ echo "Your Title Here "; }
else 
{ echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getMethodTitle()); } ?>
```

Make the same change in both files - they are different pages. Whether there are more pages has yet to be determined.

The usps_6 and usps_1 comparisons correspond to the attributes set in the html tabs when you inspect your elements. Assuming a usage of chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it by CSV file is the best and simplest way in Magento 2!

1. Create folder i18n in your custom module as:

   **app/code/Vendor/Module/i18n**
2. Create file here **en_US.csv** and write Label that you want to change as:

   "Add to Cart","Custom Label"

You can change pretty good number of labels by this way like:

```
"Add to Cart","Add to Order"
"Go to Checkout","Complete Order"
"Shopping Cart","Current Order"
"Proceed to Checkout","Proceed to Confirm"
"Summary","Details"
"Estimate Shipping and Tax","Aproximate Sum"
"You added %1 to your shopping cart.","Successfully added %1 to your current order."
"Add Your Review","Add Review"
```

Good to see other answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Updating Mage_usa.csv allows you to change label for the shipping method on frontend. Also you can rewrite Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Usps_Source_Method to add translation to the method names in the admin. Like:

```
$arr[] = array('value'=>$v, 'label'=>Mage::helper('core')->__($v));
```

Another way is to look at the usps node in config.xml for Mage_Usa module. You can redefine methods and allowed_methods nodes in your own module.